# Python regex both multiline and single line within same statement

Tags: python, regex

I am unsure how to account for an instance in which one part of the statement uses `re.M` and the other uses `re.S`. I can't seem to find a similar question or resolution.

I have this statement:

```
[re.findall('(?<!^--.*)[^\s]*_[^\s]*', i) 
    for i in re.findall('\),\s+--+(.*?)as\s\(', text,flags=re.S)]
```

Where I would like to use `re.M` for the first instance and keep `re.S` for the second instance. So, search multiline for `?<!^--.*)[^\s]*_[^\s]*` and single line for `\),\s+--+(.*?)as\s\(`

Sample text -

```
text text
),  
-- the dog jumped_over_the_moon
cat_dog as (
other text 
text 
text_text_other
text
text
```

This doesn't work as it seems to only use the second instance of `re.S`

```
[re.findall('(?<!^--.*)[^\s]*_[^\s]*', i, flags=.re.M) 
    for i in re.findall('\),\s+--+(.*?)as\s\(', text,flags=re.S)]
```

so the desired outcome is only

```
cat_dog
```

where currently the result produced is

```
jumped_over_the_moon
cat_dog
```

I would like it to skip the `--` line

Comment: With the sample text provided, what is your expected output?

Comment: My main problem is `(?<!^--.*)` is not acknowledge in the first statement. I'd like it to skip lines starting with `--` but not recognized because of `re.s`

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't get a "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern" error, because, well, look-behinds require a fixed-width pattern and `(?<!^--.*)` is _not_ a fixed-width pattern

Comment: Why not first filter out the lines starting with `--` using something like `if not line.startswith('--'): ...`

Comment: What result do you expect? `[['text_text_tex', 'text_text']]`? Also, please confirm you use `import regex as re`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i've edited for clarity

Comment: Are you using `import regex as re`? Try `[re.findall(r'(?<!^--.*)[^\s_]+_\S+', i, re.M) 
    for i in re.findall(r'\),(\s+--+.*?)as\s\(', text,flags=re.S)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Pranav, `re` in Python unlike some other regular expression engines/packages requires a fixed-width pattern for lookbehind operators. So you should modify your first regex to

```
^[^-].*?[^\s]*_[^\s]*
```

**Edit:** According to the updated question, this should be

```
^[^-].*?[^\s]*_[^\s]*(?=\sas\s\()
```

So the final loop should look like this

```
[re.findall(r'^[^-].*?[^\s]*_[^\s]*(?=\sas\s\()', i, re.M) for i in re.findall(r'\),\s+--+.*?as\s\(', text, flags=re.S)]
```

which would return `[["cat_dog"]]`.

Comment: can you explain in a bit more detail? this doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: What are you trying to exactly match and how this answer isn't working for you?

Comment: this is what i'm trying to get help with, this works if the multiline flag is tagged but my flag is single line

Comment: I am still having a hard time understanding why this fails. If you just want `cat_dog`, then you can just introduce a positive lookahead `(?=\sas\s\()` to the end of my regex.

Comment: excellent thank you! so needed the ```^```multiline indicator plus ```re.M``` ?

Comment: Yes, because `^` only makes sense if you're using a multiline flag.

Comment: And ```(?<!^--.*)``` was incorrect syntax and just hadn't thrown an error because of ```import regex as re``` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231391/discussion-between-dr-regex-and-paranormaldist).